# Start a console app with arguments line by line in C#

Tags: c#, command-line, parameters, arguments

I have a console app. This app first asks for name then you input your info and then it asks for the password. Now I want to do this automaticly with c#. Basically I want to start the process and automaticly input my name and then press enter and then input the password.  I have found lots of information on how to add one argument but that is not what im looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The main method takes an array of strings, which represent any number of parameters.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use command line arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `RedirectStandardIn` in the `ProcessStartOptions`, then write to the `Process`' `StandardInput` stream.